# Tomcat: depending the url, the css and javascript are run. why?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am trying to build a Tomcat project.

Here is my context:
In WebContent, i create a folder called 'webpages' in which I include my file About.jsp + css, javascript files.

In my /WEB-INF/web.xml, I associate /webpages/About.jsp to /about:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>About</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.supervision.servlets.About</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>About</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my java code:

```
public class Accueil extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException{ 
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/webpages/About.jsp" ).forward( request, response );
    }
}
```

My problem is:

when I use this url **localohost:8080/supervision/about** , css and javacsript are not run

[image]

but when I use this url **localohost:8080/supervision/webpages/About.jsp** , it works fine:

[image]

Do you know what is the reason of this issue ? and if yes, how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this line /webpages/about instead of /about .

Comment: thanks, i works fine :) !